# Php form (using PDO) to insert into other tables (foreign keys)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need some help, I am trying to insert into multiple tables using PDO - Can someone see what I am doing wrong - I am not getting a parse errors (nor did I set up an asset error):

Here is my form:

addcontact.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add New Contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
 <body>
 <div class="CSS_Table_Example" style="width:500px;height:350px;">
          <center>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p>
<td>      
    <tr><label for="ContactName">Contact Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ContactName" id="ContactName">
 </tr></p>
  <p>
   <tr> <label for="ContactTypeId">Contact Type:</label>

<select name="ContactTypeId">
<option value="1">Contact</option>
<option value="2">Organization</option>

</select>
</p>
<p>
<td>
       <tr> <label for="AddressTypeId">Address Type:</label>

<select name="AddressTypeId">
<option value="1">Home</option>
<option value="2">Office</option>
<option value="3">Other</option>

</select>
</p>
<p>
   <tr><label for="Address1">Address 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address1" id="Address1">
</tr></p>
<p>
   <tr><label for="Address2">Address 2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address2" id="Address1">
</tr></p>
<p>
   <tr><label for="City">City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="City" id="Address1">
</tr></p>
   <tr> <label for="StateId">State:</label>

<select name="StateId">
<option value="1">Alabama</option>
<option value="2">Alaska</option>
<option value="3">Arizona</option>
<option value="4">Arkansas</option>
<option value="5">Califorina</option>
<option value="6">Colorado</option>
<option value="7">Connecticut</option>
<option value="8">Delaware</option>
<option value="9">District of Columbia</option>
<option value="10">Florida</option>
<option value="11">Georgia</option>
<option value="12">Hawaii</option>
<option value="13">Idaho</option>
<option value="14">Illinois</option>
<option value="15">Indiana</option>
<option value="16">Iowa</option>
<option value="17">Kansas</option>
<option value="18">Kentucky</option>
<option value="19">Louisana</option>
<option value="20">Maine</option>
<option value="21">Maryland</option>
<option value="22">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="23">Michigan</option>
<option value="24">Minnesota</option>
<option value="25">Mississippi</option>
<option value="26">Missouri</option>
<option value="27">Montana</option>
<option value="28">Nebraska</option>
<option value="29">Nevada</option>
<option value="30">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="31">New Jersey</option>
<option value="32">New Mexico</option>
<option value="33">New York</option>
<option value="34">North Carolina</option>
<option value="35">North Dakota</option>
<option value="36">Ohio</option>
<option value="37">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="38">Oregon</option>
<option value="39">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="40">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="41">South Carolina</option>
<option value="42">South Dakota</option>
<option value="43">Tennessee</option>
<option value="44">Texas</option>
<option value="45">Utah</option>
<option value="46">Vermont</option>
<option value="47">Virginia</option>
<option value="48">Washington</option>
<option value="49">West Virginia</option>
<option value="50">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="51">Wyoming</option>
</select>

</tr> </p>    
<input type="submit" value="Add Record">
</tr></td>
</form>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is insert.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "root";

$dbname = "crm";

//making an array with the data received, to use as named placeholders   for INSERT by PDO.

$data = array('ContactName' => $_POST['ContactName'] , 'ContactTypeId' 
=> $_POST['ContactTypeId'],

'ContactId'=> $_POST['ContactId'],'AddressTypeId'=>  

$_POST['AddressTypeId'],'Address1'=>$_POST['Address1'],
 'Address2'=>$_POST['   
  Address2'],'City'=>$_POST['City'],'StateId'=>$_POST['StateId']); 
 try {
 // preparing database handle $dbh

 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",

 $username,$password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$currentID = mysql_inserted_id();

// query with named placeholders to avoid sql injections

$query = "INSERT INTO Contacts (ContactName, ContactTypeId)      
VALUES(:ContactName, :ContactTypeId )";

 $query2= "INSERT INTO 
 Addresses(ContactId,AddressTypeId,Address1,Address2,City,StateId) 
VALUES(:$currentID,:AddressTypeId,:Address1,:Address2,:City,:StateId)";
//statement handle $sth
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($data);
echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Comment: "I am not getting parse errors" -- so then, can you be more specific about what your code's current behaviour is?

Comment: Query2 isn't executed. The value arrays should only have values for the query it is being executed on.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang its not inserting into either table (Contacts or Addreses) I am sure i did something wrong with either the array up top or handling of query2 with inserting the mysql_inserted_id, but no errors.

Comment: `mysql_inserted_id` is another issue. You aren't using `mysql_` driver you are using pdo, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php. Although you shouldn't need that, isn't the column auto-incrementing?

Comment: @chris85 i should use lastInsertId instead then correct?

Comment: ummm it'd be closer to working that way. That ID that will return though is already in use so you'd need to increase it by 1. Why not have it auto-increment it and not insert the value yourself? Also not `:$currentID` but `:currentID`....but all that won't matter because you aren't executing that query.

Comment: table contacts primary key is auto incremented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86570/discussion-between-user130045-and-chris85).

Comment: Ahh I see what it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two arrays `$data` for `$query` & `$data1` for `$query1` and need   use `$dbh->lastInsertId()` for last id. Use the below code. I think it will work:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";

    $username = "root";

    $password = "root";

    $dbname = "crm";

    //making an array with the data received, to use as named placeholders   for INSERT by PDO.

    $data = array('ContactName' => $_POST['ContactName'] , 'ContactTypeId' 
    => $_POST['ContactTypeId']);

    $data1=array('AddressTypeId'=>$_POST['AddressTypeId'],'Address1'=>$_POST['Address1'],
     'Address2'=>$_POST['   
      Address2'],'City'=>$_POST['City'],'StateId'=>$_POST['StateId']); 
     try {
     // preparing database handle $dbh

     $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",

     $username,$password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    // query with named placeholders to avoid sql injections

    $query = "INSERT INTO Contacts (ContactName, ContactTypeId)      
    VALUES(:ContactName, :ContactTypeId )";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute($data);

    $currentID = $dbh->lastInsertId();

     $query2= "INSERT INTO 
     Addresses(ContactId,AddressTypeId,Address1,Address2,City,StateId) 
    VALUES($currentID,:AddressTypeId,:Address1,:Address2,:City,:StateId)";

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query2);
    $sth->execute($data1);

    //statement handle $sth

    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;
    ?>
```